# Python threading & multiprocessing error?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is `threading.Timer` and `multiprocessing.Process` spawn another process which is independent to others theading or process? Example my code goes below the following, assuming it goes one round of the `if` statement which make it execute the `multiprocessing.Process` and `threading.Timer`, and now is 20secs, so by right it still waiting for 40secs to get the code done but if it execute into the `if` statement again, will it get any errors or something? will it pass the second round of var to the `myFunction2` and execute another `myFunction3` on top of the first round?

```
def myFunction3():
    #some stuffs

def myFunction2(a,b):
    time.sleep(60)
    subprocess.Popen([.....],....) #with a var
    subprocess.Popen([.....],....) #with b var

def myFunction():
    if data in a:
       subprocess.Popen([.....],....)
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myFunction2,args=(a,b))
       p.start()
       threading.Timer(60, myFunction3).start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
       myFunction()
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myFunction2,args=(a,b))
p.start()
```

will create a new process and run the function `myFunction2` in that process.

This:

```
threading.Timer(60, myFunction3).start()
```

will create a new thread in the current process and run the function `myFunction3` in that thread.

A process can contain more than one thread, all of which share the same address space, but processes don't share the same address space with each other.

Comment: So am i right to say that `multiprocessing.Process` will passed the two variables to the new process which is independent and store them in the new process each time? So `threading.Timer` is independent but running on the same current process which also can pass variables independently?

Comment: You should remember that in Python a variable is just a name which refers to an object. `myFunction2` will be running in a different process, so the object to which the name refers will be copied into that process's address space and will therefore be independent. On the other hand, `myFunction3` will be running merely in a different thread in the same address space, so the object to which the name refers will be shared, which matters if the object is mutable, e.g. a list.

Comment: So in my case if `myFunction3` is to remove all elements in a list. Then now it just went one round of `if` statement and the timing of the timer has 40 seconds left to execute `myFunction3`, and another another of `if` statement execute again. So my question is will it replace the current `threading.Timer` or it will has two `threading.Timer` which are different from each other to execute?

Comment: Let say if first round of `if` statement the object it get is `1` then pass it to `threading.Timer` and while it has 40 seconds left to execute the `threading.Timer`, now another round of `if` statement is execute again. This time it get an object is `2` and pass it to  `threading.Timer`, will it replace the object which the first round has been assigned or will it spawn two different `threading.Timer` but just the timing different and the first get `1`, second get `2`? Hope you understand my question. Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: `threading.Timer` is a subclass of `Thread`. It will create a thread which will run the function after the specified time. If you call `threading.Timer` 2 times, it will create 2 threads; if you call it 3 times, it will create 3 threads; etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental problem with this code: multiprocessing.Process uses fork() to create new processes (unless you are using Windows). It is generally accepted that using fork() is bad practice in a multi-threaded application; [here's a good article](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them).

Having said that, it should be *possible* to make this work if you are careful.